# Trigger a GTK application from CHROOT during LightDM startup

Tags: chroot, gtk, lightdm

I am trying run a GTK application with chrooted environment. Mentioned are the lightdm settings which I have set.

**System configuration:**

```
OS : Debian 8
chroot FS: Debian 6
Windows manager : LXDE
```

**Lightdm.conf**

```
display-stopped-script=
greeter-setup-script=
session-setup-script=/opt/startups/Start.sh
session-cleanup-script=
autologin-guest=false
autologin-user=ragav
```

Start.sh will set the mount parameters and run the chroot command.

**CHROOT Settings**

```
 mount -o bind /dev /opt/debian6/dev
 mount -o bind /proc /opt/debian6/proc
 mount -o bind /dev/pts /opt/debian6/dev/pts
 mount -o bind /sys /opt/debian6/sys
 mount -o bind /home /opt/debian6/home
 cp /etc/resolv.conf /opt/debian6/etc/resolv.conf
 cp /etc/hosts /opt/debian6/etc/hosts

 sudo chroot /opt/debian6 /bin/bash -c "su - -c /opt/app.sh&"
```

This setting triggers the application to get started but it throws **(app:4846): Gtk-WARNING : cannot open display: :0**

However, when i kill my apps and run the same script from **Uxterm terminal** or **AUTO login as ROOT** I notice my application running smoothly.

Request some guidance on addressing this issue.

Comment: Similar question : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10743/what-to-do-to-run-gui-java-app-in-chrooted-environment